# laravel: open login modal instead of redirecting to login page

Tags: laravel, authentication, bootstrap-modal

Generally We redirect users to the login page if he tries to access authenticated routes. I would like to open a login modal instead of redirecting users to login page. So when he tries to hit the route, login modal should pop up. How do I do that in laravel? Need suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

the idea of having Login in Modal, is include login form on all pages, and just show it on user click via JS.

For your purpose redirecting to another route an show login, you can use session

```
return redirect('home')->with('openLogin');
```

And in View:

```
@if (session('openLogin'))
    //some js function that will open your hidden modal
    //if you use bootstrap modal
    <script>
       $('#myLoginModal').modal('show');
    </script>
@endif
```

Or you can even have it with simple html/css:

```
<div class="loginModal @if(session('openLogin')) open @else closed @endif"></div>
```

And make some changes in css:

```
.open{
   display:block;
}
.closed{
   display:none;
}
```

So there is a lot of ways to go, choose one that will suite you.

Take a look on this tutorial: Take this Tutorial: [Here](http://laravel.sillo.org/formulaire-modal/)